# Can Apex properties take input- An encapsulation question?

Tags: apex, oop

Say I have a proprerty, and I want to pass in an input to it in the setter, can I do that?

This snippet below is well encapsulated java code. but it's a bit verbose.

```
private Decimal weight;

public Decimal getWeight(){
    //...
}
public void setWeight(Decimal inputWeight){
    //error checking on inputWeight, and set member or throw variable
}
```

To make it less verbose, i'd like for it to take a property form. Can I do that?
One issue I see off the bat is the accesser is less restrictive than the property.

```
private Decimal weight
{
    get;
    public set{
        //take in an input and do stuff
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent version of your Java snippet would actually be:

```
public Decimal weight {
    get;
    set {
        // Do something with value
    }
}
```

Or, if you really wanted to have a backing variable:

```
Decimal m_weight;
public Decimal weight {
    get { return m_weight; }
    set {
        // Do something with value
        m_weight = value;
    }
}
```

In Apex Code, there's rarely a reason do this, as a matter of performance. I'd use the first example I wrote.

However, sometimes having a backing variable can help reduce the side effects caused by using custom getters and setters in Visualforce pages, because they have an undefined order of execution. Usually, you'd do this if you had two variables that are interlocked, like this:

```
Boolean readOnly;
public Boolean isReadWrite {
    get { return !readOnly; }
    set { readOnly = !value; }
}
public Boolean isReadOnly {
    get { return readOnly; }
    set { readOnly = value; }
}
```

This prevents the otherwise (hopefully obvious) stack overflow you'd get from recursive calling of getters and setters.

Comment: This is good stuff! You rock! In your first code snippet. how are we achieving encapulation if the weight variable is public?

Comment: @user11235813 In the first example, the backing variable is completely hidden, since it can only be accessed by its getter or setter, which is really all your Java example is doing. Your apex example with the getter and setter would be equivalent to writing `Decimal weight; private Decimal getWeight() { ... } public void setWeight(Decimal weight) { ... }`, which is clearly not the same as the Java version with a backing variable. The second version I wrote most closely identifies with your Java example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Here is a short example

```
public class BasicProperty {
   public integer prop {
      get { return prop; }
      set { prop = value; }
   }
}
```

and

```
BasicProperty bp = new BasicProperty();
bp.prop = 5;                   // Calls set accessor
System.assert(bp.prop == 5);   // Calls get accessor
```

And as per Salesforce docs

- The set accessor is similar to a method whose return type is void.
- When you assign a value to the property, the set accessor is invoked
  with an argument that provides the new value.
- When the set accessor
  is invoked, the system passes an implicit argument to the setter
  called value of the same data type as the property. Properties cannot
  be defined on interface.
- Apex properties are based on their
  counterparts in C#, with the following differences: Properties
  provide storage for values directly. You do not need to create
  supporting members for storing values. It is possible to create
  automatic properties in Apex. For more information, see Using
  Automatic Properties.

You can check more details in [Apex Properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm)